# Heroku + Rack App + Active Support Timezones

Tags: ruby, heroku

I have a pretty simple Rack app that's defined in a file called `config.ru`:

```
require './environment'

 class Ryan
   def self.call(env)
    [200, { "Content-Type" => "text/html" }, [Time.zone.now]]
   end
 end

 run Ryan
```

In `environment.rb`, there's this:

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/time/zones'
require 'active_support/time_with_zone'
require 'active_support/core_ext/time/conversions'

Time.zone = 'Sydney'
```

And in the `Gemfile`:

```
source "http://rubygems.org"

gem 'rack'
gem 'tzinfo'
gem 'activesupport'
```

When I run this locally, it works! Huge success.

However, when I deploy this application to Heroku it fails entirely with this showing in the logs:

```
2012-03-01T02:01:55+00:00 app[web.1]: [2012-03-01 02:01:55] INFO  ruby 1.9.2 (2011-07-09) [x86_64-linux]
2012-03-01T02:01:55+00:00 app[web.1]: [2012-03-01 02:01:55] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
2012-03-01T02:01:55+00:00 app[web.1]: [2012-03-01 02:01:55] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=1 port=27368
2012-03-01T02:01:56+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2012-03-01T02:01:57+00:00 app[web.1]: [2012-03-01 02:01:57] ERROR NoMethodError: undefined method `now' for nil:NilClass
2012-03-01T02:01:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.1/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
2012-03-01T02:01:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:70:in `run'
2012-03-01T02:01:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   /app/config.ru:8:in `call'
2012-03-01T02:01:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:111:in `service'
2012-03-01T02:01:57+00:00 app[web.1]:   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183:in `block in start_thread'
```

So... what's the dealio here? Is Heroku running this in a different kind of process and so that's why it can't be found?

Comment: what Heroku stack is this *not* running on?

Comment: nevermind, seems like vanilla cedar

Answer (score 0):

Weird, this did not run for me locally ,
Ruby 1.9.2p180 and gems,

```
i18n (0.6.0) 
multi_json (1.1.0) 
activesupport (3.2.1) 
rack (1.4.1) 
tzinfo (0.3.31) 
bundler (1.0.18)
```

This did,

```
  require './environment'

  class Ryan
    def self.call(env)
      Time.zone = "Sydney"
      [200, { "Content-Type" => "text/html" }, [Time.zone.now.to_s]]
    end
  end

  run Ryan
```

More information on your local environment may shed some light on why is it happenning.

Comment: ruby 1.9.2 (2011-07-09) == ruby 1.9.2p290 AFAIK

Comment: i think that stack trace is heroku's .. not ryan's local

Comment: I know, but I assumed he's running the same one locally :)

Answer (score 0):

That will work with Thin instead of WEBrick.

Add Thin gem to your `Gemfile` then create a `Procfile`:

`web: bundle exec thin start -p $PORT`

It worked for me on cedar stack.

As to why it did work with Thin and not WEBrick: I don't have a clue!

http://ryan-cedar.herokuapp.com/